# Laravel error Lock database vs Transaction break

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, locking, pessimistic

Anyone help me, please!.
In my project, i have transaction with lock record:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Testing extends Command {
    protected function handling()
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $posts = Posts::lockForUpdate()->find(1);

            //run step 1

            //run step 2

            //run step 3

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

in my case, i call it from command, when it running:

```
php artisan test:run

...
running step 1
...
...
running step 2
..
..
Ctrl C

-> quit command.
```

Transaction not commit and lock record forever.

Can i commit transaction on command force quit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `DB::beginTransaction();` then you need to commit using `DB:commit();` as

```
DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $posts = Posts::lockForUpdate()->find(1);

            //run step 1

            //run step 2

            //run step 3
            DB::commit();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
        }
```

Comment: when i cancel command, 
```
php artisan test:run

...
running step 1
...
...
running step 2
..
..
Ctrl C

-> quit command.
```

The transaction not commit, Lock not release. So, i update database with record locked not available.

How can commit transaction on force quit command laravel